# sharing a iPhone static library

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, static-libraries

I need to clarify one doubt here:

When we create a static library and use them inside another project, why do we need to add the .xcodeproj file (for which this static library was created) reference in the code?

Shouldn't we be able to just give our library to anyone so that they could use in their project without needing our .xcodeproj file. If this is possible then what are the steps for it?

Comment: You generally add the .xcodeproj for automatic dependency generation. If you update the build configuration of your top-level project or change the code of your library project, Xcode will handle automatic compilation and linking, whereas using a generated library means you will have to manually track those changes and recompile the library to match (e.g with or without debug symbols).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them the compiled `.a` files (one for ARM and one for Intel) and any header files that you want made public... that's pretty much it right there.

Comment: I did that but the issue is that they are not able to run it and looks like my lib (.a) is searching for other libs at a wrong path :-(!

Comment: I am getting this error:
ld: warning: directory '/Users/abhinav/iProject/MyApp/../Project/trunk/client/src/Root/scanner' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Users/abhinav/iProject/MyApp/../Project/trunk/client/src/Root' following -L not found

Comment: ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LSLScannerController in //Users/abhinav/iProject/MyApp/../Project/trunk/client/src/Root/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMyLib.a(LSLScannerController.o) and Linea/libScannerLibrary.a(LSLScannerController.o)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: libMyLib.a and libScannerLibrary.a both contain the same symbols. Have them drop one or the other from the project.